# Visualize a big directed graph

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, directed-graph

I have a text-file with connections that I want to visualize. I'm fine if it's something that's generated server side in whatever language, i suppose python would be the way to go, but I'm open to suggestions. It would be great to have some HTML/JS visualization of the result, but just an image works fine as well.

My data looks like this:

```
1,2
2,3
3,1
4,5
5,4
```

The first value is the FROM NODE and the second value is the TO NODE.

If the distance from one node back to itself is just ONE other node, i want it to be orange. If the distance is TWO nodes it should be GREEN.

Based on the data above the graph should look like this:

[image: How my graph should look]

The data I have is about half a million rows.

I'm a bit lost with the graph-lingo to be honest. I understand that what I want is a directed graph, but what are the two different relationships above called? (the direct one 4<->5 and the two-step one 1->2->3->1)

Comment: You seem to be asking two question: 1.) if anyone has any tips for code or libraries that will allow you to draw directed graphs to HTML or images and 2.) what the terminology is for the two types of edges. The first question is purely opinion-based and is not suitable for StackOverflow - pick a platform, try to write something and ask questions about problems you run into on SO. The second question is unrelated, they're edges in a directed graph, and a bidirected edge between 4 and 5.

Comment: Thank you. Edges was the word I didn't know! I don't really care about the language it's done it. I know that Python is often used for math things, but I'm open to any solution that can give me the result. I found a software called NodeBox that seems to be able to do what I want, still trying to figure it out.